# python Flask, TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, api, flask

I'm studying Flask very recently and trying to create API.
However, when It request json data, this error occurs.
    **if content['words'] is not None:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable**

could anyone can help this?
Thanks
my code is below:

```py
    @app.route("/process",methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def process():
    content = request.json
    words = {}
    if content['words'] is not None:
        for data in content['words'].values():
            words[data['word']] = data['weight']
    process_from_text(content['text'], content['maxCount'], content['minLength'], words)
    result = {'result':True}
    return jsonify(result
```

Comment: It should be `content = request.json()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
okay, I put () at the end of json, then this error occurred
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: How are you passing the data to the route?

Comment: I'm passing dummy json data with Chrome's Talend API Tester

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely that request is not a valid json request. If that is the case then content will be equal to None which means it is not subscriptable.